# get specific item from combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="language" DataSourceID="TerminalLanguageDTS" DataValueField="TERMINAL_LANGUAGE_ID" DataTextField="TERMINAL_LANGUAGE_NAME" runat="server" Width="175px" > </asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:button id="edit" runat="server onClick="edit_Click" Text="Edit">

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="TerminalLanguageDTS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:Kernel_dbConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TERMINAL_LANGUAGE_NAME],[TERMINAL_LANGUAGE_ID] FROM [terminal_languages]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

what i want to do is when the user click on edit just a specific languages from the language dropdown should be visible like for example if the drop down contains : english french and japanese as languages on page load it should have just english and french on edit click

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409544/removing-list-items-from-the-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to remove one item by its value from your dropdownlist like this on edit click:

```
ListItem myitem = language.Items.FindByValue("itemtoreomve");
if (myitem != null)
{
    language.Items.Remove(myitem);
}
```

You can remove item by text as well:

```
  ListItem myitem = language.Items.FindByText("itemtoreomve");
```